# Add a listener to a child inside of a firebase generated key?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Given the layout

```
+ activity
  + -K5p_pBXog4kb0SVLXxj
    text:'something',
    when:111
    + thread
      + -K5paF53zm3cuudP9FUQ 
        id:8,
        text:'something else'
```

Is there a way to add a listener to any new "thread" inserts inside of activity like /activity/*/thread?

When new activities get added I am getting the feed on those but when a thread is appended nothing triggers.  Do I need to move the [thread] section out to it's own root and match thread ID's with activity ID's to know when a thread comment is made against the main activity thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the answer based upon your comment.

You want to listen to `/activity/$theid/thread/$threadId`:

Rather than nesting, break out the `/thread/$threadId` into it's own location at the root.

```
{
  "threadActivity": {
     "$activityId": {
        "$threadId" : {

        } 
     }
   } 
}
```

Now when a new thread is added you can just listen to `/threadActivity/$activityId`:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my>.firebaseio.com/threadActivity');
var activityRef = ref.child('some-id');
activityRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  // will update you for every child at the location and each child added
  console.log(snap.val()); 
});
```

Comment: It's for a web platform and the main issue is any logged in user can make a main thread which updates across all browsers just fine but when the admin adds their comment to the main thread we add it via "/activity/theid#/thread" but no other clients see the update.  I can't add a listener to each /activity/activity ID #/thread that's why I was asking if it's possible to do /activity/*/thread - then when a comment is added I can pull the activity ID and update the proper UI element.  I may have to re-think how this is being implemented.

Comment: That makes sense. I updated my answer. Things will be much easier if you re-work your data structure.

Comment: Adjusted like your example and now the feed works great.

Comment: Let me know if there's any other considerations for the answer. If not please mark it as accepted, it's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Comment: Since you stated my answered worked for you, can you please mark it as accepted? This is the way Stackoverflow works. If there is anything else I should know about your question, please let me know.