# Indexing 2nd child node in Firebase for REST Api access

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using REST API to query Firebase.

Rule is set as below :

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "user": {
            ".indexOn": "type"
        }
    }
}
```

When querying the below URL using GET method

```
https://exampleurl.firebaseio.com/user/9001.json
```

Response :

```
{
  "name": "Rohit",
  "person": {
    "-KLk3p3kUWg2j9p16kTw": {
      "mobile": "9002",
      "name": "Adarsh",
      "type": "D"
    },
    "-KLk4x2V_hfZwlsh6PMo": {
      "mobile": "9003",
      "name": "Manas",
      "type": "D"
    },
    "-KLk5-UPefdSMarC5VCQ": {
      "mobile": "9004",
      "name": "Sagar",
      "place": "thane",
      "type": "C"
    }
  }
}
```

> I get error when using filtering query in GET method

```
https://exampleurl.firebaseio.com/user/9001.json?orderBy="type"&startAt="D"
```

**Response** :

```
{
  "error": "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"type\", for path \"/user/9001\", to the rules"
}
```

I tried using below rule. But firebase does not allow me to save.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "user/9001": {
            ".indexOn": "type"
        }
    }
}
```

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363511) speaks about listening on change. While my question is on Indexing.

Comment: It isn't possible to define an index on such a dynamic path. You'll have to modify your data structure to allow this sort of querying. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363511/add-a-listener-to-a-child-inside-of-a-firebase-generated-key

Answer (score 1):

After searching and spending quite a time on the problem, was able to figure out the solution for indexing 2nd node in Firebase.

Firebase supports wild card for indexing.

New Rule, which solved my problem:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "user": {
           "$person":{
            ".indexOn": "type"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is "$person" the person id (9001) or you just wrote "$person" ?

Comment: @AhmedHesham. You can add any name with `$` as a prefix. This will act as the wild card.